Where to find textstring in Linux/Dovecot
I have installed the iRedMail email server script on an Ubuntu 22.04
with Nginx.
Now, when I create a new email account,
the user gets an email when he logs in the first time. 
It’s a welcome email with a link to where you should login,
but the link is totally wrong. 
I have asked in the iRedMail forum, but all answer I got is that
the installation doesn’t install anything to send out welcome messages. 
I have tried to find the text string using grep,
but it seems to hang and doesn’t show anything. 
Can anyone hint about a better way to find this string?
root@mail:~# grep -r -i 'Welcome and thank you' /
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register: Invalid argument
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush: Permission denied
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/route/flush: Permission denied
grep: /proc/sys/vm/compact_memory: Permission denied
grep: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
grep: /proc/kmsg: Resource temporarily unavailable


... explain – or even show – what’s wrong with the link.

Well, in the first place, there should not be a welcome message at all. 
It’s nothing I have configured. 
The welcome plugin in Dovecot is not enabled. 
And, if it was to be correct, it should lead to the roundcube login mail.mxmail.pro/mail. This is the text:

Welcome and thank you for registering at Mx Mail!
Your account has now been created and you can log in by using your email address and password by visiting our website or at the following URL:
https://mxmail.pro/index.php? route-account/login&language=en-gb


1/2 The best way to find configuration files is to read the associated documentation. For example, starting with Install iRedMail on Debian or Ubuntu Linux one is quickly led to the section Important things you MUST know after installation which links to Locations of configuration and log files of major components

2/2 Since you've not explained how "the link is totally wrong" it's going to be hard to give a specific solution. Perhaps you could edit your question to explain - or even show - what's wrong with the link. While you're editing please can you provide a link for "the iredmail email server script"

Well, in first place there should not be a welcome message at all. Its nothing I have configured. The welcome plugin in Dovecot is not enabled.

Please say that in your question

"I have tried to find the teststring using grep but it seems to hang and dont show anything" - I suspect it was still searching. Your command asked your computer to search through every single file for the phrase. This will inevitably take some time

(1) Please explain what the question has to do with Dovecot.  Please do not respond in comments (or by posting a non-answer); [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.   (2) ISTM that /proc is not a useful place to search, and may contain things that will “hang”.  If Chris’s advice doesn’t resolve your issue, it might be better to search in /etc, /usr and /var.

And /opt, @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'
